# button click transfer to selected column from a gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 web forms the first one is set as the start page, which include two buttons(for example: button A & Button B), when I click one of the buttons it transfer to the second web form (that includes a gridview).

```
                      *My gridview have 4 columns*
```

I want when I click button A, it shows the first 2 columns 
and when I clcik button B, it shows the last 2 columns.

Comment: show your gridview code?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, and here is the code                                                  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ToString ());
            bool openConn = (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open);
     
        }

        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  {}